# how can i use nested partial view in razor mvc view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have one big problem .I tried more way but i can not achieve the solution and i don't know why ?!

I have an MVC web application that I have to create 9 view for create of one of my model. I create one view for create and in create view I used **`div`** and inside each **`div`**, I want to render one of these partial view and in each of these 9 partial views, I used 2 or 3 partial view: it means, I used nested partial view.  but when I do this work by this code  any java-script code of  partial-views dos not work i don't know why and how can I handle it thanks in advance.

`VIEW(create)..>partial-view(pvinputfaulty)...>partial-view(invoiceitemgrid)...> partial-view (partbookletpopup)`

```
         <div class="editor-label">
              invoicetype:
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                @Html.RadioButtonForEnum(model => model.Invoice_.Invoice_Mode)
            </div>

        <div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                input type :
            </div>
            <div style="display: none" id="inputinvoicetype" class="radio">
                @Html.RadioButtonForEnum(model => model.Invoice_.InputInvoice_Type)

            </div>
            <div style="display: none" id="outputinvoicetype" class="radio">
                @Html.RadioButtonForEnum(model => model.Invoice_.OutInvoice_Type)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="PartialViewContent">
         <div id="divPV1"></div> 
         <div id="divPV2"></div> 
         <div id="divPV3"></div> 
         <div id="divPV4"></div> 
         <div id="divPV5"></div> 
         <div id="divPV6"></div> 
         <div id="divPV7"></div> 
         <div id="divPV8"></div> 
         <div id="divPV9"></div> 
            </div>    </div>


}


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[type=radio]").change(function () {
            var invoicemode = $(this).val();
            if (invoicemode == "Output") {
                $('.mainContent  #divPV1').empty();
                $('.mainContent  #divPV2').empty();
                $('.mainContent  #divPV3').empty();
                $('.mainContent  #divPV4').empty();
                $('.mainContent  #divPV5').empty();
                $('.mainContent  #divPV6').empty();
                $('.mainContent  #divPV7').empty();
                $('.mainContent  #divPV8').empty();
                $('.mainContent  #divPV9').empty();
                $("#inputinvoicetype").hide();
                $("#outputinvoicetype").show();
            }
        });
    })




        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#inputinvoicetype input[type=radio]").change(function () {
                var radio = $(this).val();

                if (radio == "faulty") {
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV2').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV3').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV4').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV5').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV6').empty();

                   $('.mainContent  #divPV1').load('@Url.Action("PVInputFaulty", "Invoice")');

                }
                else if (radio == "overplus") {
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV1').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV3').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV4').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV5').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV6').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV2').load('@Url.Action("PVInputFaulty", "Invoice")');

                }

                else if (radio == "Reconstructed") {
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV2').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV1').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV4').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV5').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV6').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV3').load('@Url.Action("PVInputFaulty", "Invoice")');

                }
                else if (radio == "Bought") {
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV2').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV3').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV1').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV5').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV6').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV4').load('@Url.Action("PVInputFaulty", "Invoice")');

                }

                else if (radio == "New_pieces") {
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV2').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV3').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV4').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV1').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV6').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV5').load('@Url.Action("PVInputFaulty", "Invoice")');

                }
                else {
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV2').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV3').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV4').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV5').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV1').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV6').load('@Url.Action("PVInputFaulty", "Invoice")');

                }
            })
        })

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#outputinvoicetype input[type=radio]").change(function () {
                var radio = $(this).val();

                if (radio == "Installed_in_trains") {

                    $('.mainContent  #divPV9').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV8').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV7').load('@Url.Action("PVInputFaulty", "Invoice")');

                }
                else if (radio == "Useless") {
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV9').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV7').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV8').load('@Url.Action("PVInputFaulty", "Invoice")');

                }

                else {
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV7').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV8').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV9').load('@Url.Action("PVInputFaulty", "Invoice")');

                }

            })
         })


        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input[type=radio]").change(function () {
                var invoicemode1 = $(this).val();
                if (invoicemode1 == "Input") {
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV1').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV2').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV3').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV4').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV5').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV6').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV7').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV8').empty();
                    $('.mainContent  #divPV9').empty();
                    $("#inputinvoicetype").show();
                    $("#outputinvoicetype").hide();
                }
            });
        })

    </script>
```

Comment: Your JavaScript code is highly inefficient. Why not using  `$('#PartialViewContent > div').empty()`? Can you be more specific and define _does not work_?

Comment: i am not very good in javascript and jquery  when i clicked in one button click event in jquery function that is in partbookletpopup partial view it dosent work

Comment: Can you post the rendered markup or reproduce the problem in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: i cannot do this beacuse i have nested partial view each partial view has multiple jquery function this problem occuerd becuse i think when i want render all partial view dynamically by jquery it can not find all my jquery functions inside partial views i dont know how fix this problem

Comment: try loading your javascript after the partial view is loaded.  Load the partial, then call a function that has all of your radio change, button clicks, etc inside.